# Laplace's equation of a disk of radius 1

Tags: partial-derivative

I am asked to show that 
$$u(r,\theta)=\frac{2}{\pi}\arctan\left(\frac{2r \sin\theta}{1-r^2}\right)$$ satisfies the Laplace equation in a disk of radius 1.

I have tried to take the partial derivatives with respect to $r$ and $\theta$ and plug into the equation of a disk with polar coordinates.  I have tried for hours and cannot figure this problem out.

Please help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint. You should verify that
$$r\frac{\partial}{\partial r}\left(r \frac{\partial f}{\partial r}\right)+\frac{\partial^2f}{\partial \theta^2}=0.$$
If you prefer to use cartesian coordinates let 
$$g(x,y)=\arctan\left(\frac{2y}{1-x^2-y^2}\right)$$
(the factor $2/\pi$ can be left out) and verify
$$\frac{\partial^2 g}{\partial x^2}+\frac{\partial^2 g}{\partial y^2}=0.$$
In order to simplify the long computation you could consider $$g(x,y)=\arctan\left(A(x,y)\right)\quad \mbox{ with }\quad
A(x,y)=\frac{2y}{1-x^2-y^2}.
$$
Its laplacian is zero iff
$$-2A(A_x^2+A_y^2)+(1+A^2)\cdot(A_{xx}+A_{yy})=0.$$

Comment: I tried the polar and could not get it.  The partials were too crazy for me to understand.

Comment: That will probably help.  How did you derive the cartesian coordinates of the two variable function?

Comment: @David House To avoid long computations you could break it in two parts.See my edited answer. It works.

Comment: I will try that.  Thank you.

Comment: @David House Note that $x=r\cos(\theta)$ and $y=r\sin(\theta)$.

Comment: Part 2. asks to show that as r →1, u(r,θ) = 1 on the upper semicircle and u(r,θ) = -1 on the lower semicircle.  Any hints for this one?

Comment: @David House Evaluate $\lim_{t\to\pm\infty}\arctan(t)$.

Answer (score 0):

When I saw "tried for hours" got me worried. So without wasting time doing manually, I opted to do it with Maple.

```
PDE:=1/r*Diff(r*diff(u(r,theta),r),r)+1/r^2*diff(u(r,theta),theta$2);

ans:=u(r, theta)=2/Pi*arctan(2*r*sin(theta)/(1-r^2));

pdetest(ans, PDE)
```

> 0

The output of the `pdetest` command is `0` shows that your proposed function $u(t,\theta)$ is a solution to the Laplace equation in polar coordinates.

Comment: unfortunately, I have to do it by hand.